# Huawei Honor 10 blocked Bluetooth when app is running

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I`m development network radio app for Android API 21-29 and all worked fine but one cases confuses me. On Huawei Honor 10 when my app started playing and trying to switch on the Bluetooth nothing works. Device turn-off Bluetooth and all. I add this permission in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

If Bluetooth turn on before playing, he turn off right after start play.
I used this method when app send **mediasession.OnPlay**

```java
@Override
public void onPlay() {
    if (!exoPlayer.getPlayWhenReady()) {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayerService.class));
        if (stationsRepository == null)
            return;
        station = stationsRepository.getCurrent();
        bitrate = Connectivity.currentBitrate;
        String stream = station.getStreamByBitrate(bitrate);
        prepareToPlay(Uri.parse(stream));
        mediaSession.setQueueTitle(station.getTitle());
        if (!audioFocusRequested) {
            audioFocusRequested = true;

            int audioFocusResult;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                audioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusRequest);
            } else {
                audioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusChangeListener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
            }
            if (audioFocusResult != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED)
                return;
        }

        mediaSession.setActive(true);

        registerReceiver(becomingNoisyReceiver, new IntentFilter(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY));

        exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 1).build());
    currentState = PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING;
    refreshNotificationAndForegroundStatus(currentState);
}
```

On same devices uses Android 10, Android 8, Android 7 all work is fine.
Can anyone help me fix with this.

P.S. Sorry for my English. This is the first time when I ask a question in this language.

Update: Tested on Huawei P30 lite and catch this bug too.

Comment: hi@Смирнов Денис,Based on the information provided above, it is hard to reproduce the problem. Can you provide the test APK for us to reproduce the issue? You can send you test apk to hmscore@huawei.com.We will locate this issue as soon as we receive it.

Comment: @shirley, I`m send apk to hmscore@huawei.com, but did not receive an answer

Comment: hi@Смирнов Денис, seems like we don't found your email yet. May I ask when you sent it?

Comment: @shirley, i sent it on august 5. Now I will duplicate

Comment: hi@Смирнов Денис, we have received your mail,Can you send it in the form of a file, the GitHub link you sent to us we can't open it.

Comment: @shirley, I apologize, this is my mistake, I changed the visibility of the repository. The mail does not allow you to attach the apk, please open my repository
https://github.com/denistouch/RecordMini

Comment: hi@Смирнов Денис, I installed app on Huawei P40 lite, bluetooth switch off when start playing audio. When app work in background (not playing audio), I switch on bluetooth and it swich off throw 4-5 seconds.
Nokia 6: app hasn't problem with bluetooth.

Comment: @shirley, What do you think could be the matter?